# git how to include vendor directory in Zend Framework 2

Tags: git, zend-framework2

I want to include "vendor" and all its subdirectories in my git repository, because i'm editing external modules a lot. I tried excluding "vendor/" in .gitignore file but it doesn't work, neither deleting ALL .gitignore and .gitmodules files in my project, so what else could prevent syncing of that directory?

Comment: Take a look at `.git/info/exclude` file or a possible .git repository inside the vendors itself.

Comment: Thank You again man, i resolved this issue! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, i figure out that this issue comes if there are repos inside the main repo, as Paulo Bu suggested. You are supposed to keep these repos updated adding them as submodules to your project, but this isn't my need. As i'm changing their code and adding stuffs, to be able to commit their changes i just deleted the hidden folder ".git" making these folders under "vendor" just normal folders, and not anymore .git repositories!